# Spring AOP Pointcut if condition

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am facing an issue with **pointcuts**, I am trying to enable the `@Around` when the log.isDebugEnabled is true for this I am trying the following code:

```java
@Pointcut("within(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger..*)")
    public boolean isDebugEnabled() {
        return log.isDebugEnabled();
    }
```

and for testing purposes, I have two aspects configured

```java
@AfterThrowing(value = "!isDebugEnabled()", throwing = "exception")
```

and

```java
@Around(value = "isDebugEnabled()")
```

But all the times when I try to execute the code it always goes to `@AfterThrowing`, and it is not clear for me what I am doing wrong!

I am using aspectJWeaver 1.8.9, with Spring `MVC 4.3`!

Here is a sample class emulating the issue:

```java
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

@Component
@Aspect
public class SampleAspect {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SampleAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("within(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger..*)")
    public boolean isDebugEnabled() {
        return log.isDebugEnabled();
    }

    @AfterThrowing(value = " !isDebugEnabled()", throwing = "exception")
    public void getCalledOnException(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception exception) {

        log.error("Method " + joinPoint.getSignature() + " Throws the exception " + exception.getStackTrace());
    }

    //Never execute around method even when log.isDebugEnabled() = true
    @Around(value = "isDebugEnabled()")
    public Object aroundTest(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {

        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();

        final Object proceed;
        try {
            proceed = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        stopWatch.stop();
        log.debug("It took " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeSeconds() + " seconds to be proceed");

        return proceed;
    }
}
```

**edit**,
I tried to use if() from [aspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html), but it didn't work in my project either.

```java
@Pointcut("call(* *.*(int)) && args(i) && if()")
     public static boolean someCallWithIfTest(int i) {
        return i > 0;
     }
```

Not sure if I need to add a different import or so, but I didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: What exception gets thrown ? Please share the stack trace

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception, it just executes ```@AfterThrowing``` all the time instead of executing the ```@Around``` when the log.isDebugEnabled() is true

Comment: Unfortunately, there is so much wrong with your code, I don't even know where to begin explaining. So why don't we start fresh and you first explain **_what_** you are trying to achieve and not just **_how_** you think it should be done? For example, why does your pointcut try to match classes from Apache Commons Logging? I also need to see some of the target classes you are trying to intercept. Ideally, a little [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub incl. Maven build would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points from [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop)

> == Spring AOP Capabilities and Goals
>
> Spring AOP currently supports only method execution join points
>   (**advising the execution of methods on Spring beans**)
>
> === Declaring a Pointcut
>
> In the @AspectJ annotation-style of AOP, a pointcut signature is provided
>   by a regular method definition, and the pointcut expression is
>   indicated by using the @Pointcut annotation (**the method serving as the
>   pointcut signature must have a void return type**).

Apache commons classes are not managed by Spring container . So the following will not be honoured.

```
@Pointcut("within(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger..*)")
```

Following pointcut method is not valid

```
public boolean isDebugEnabled() {
        return log.isDebugEnabled();
    }
```

Comment: that is a good point, In fairness, I'd tried to use the if() from AspectJ but I didn't manage to make it work, but basically here https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html is a sample how I am trying to use it.


     @Pointcut("call(* *.*(int)) && args(i) && if()")
     public static boolean someCallWithIfTest(int i) {
        return i > 0;
     }